# Random forest models and external validation

Tags: random-forest, reproducible-research

How can a random forest model be published so that it also can be externally validated? Is it possible to get an average of the node split values from the ensemble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have it fully reproducible, the only way is to dump the model in your statistical environment's native format and bind as a supplementary material.
The other option is to supply precise info how it was built (with random seed).

The averaged tree you propose would produce different predictions than the original model, probably much less accurate.

Comment: In other words it is impossible to validate the findings in a published model on another dataset without having the actual model present-And that would require the new dataset to be run through my "black-box" rf model for prediction?

Comment: Yup; this is just a nature of black-boxes. However note that even if you write some regression model coefficients on a piece of paper, it would not represent the model exactly because of digit cutoff and binary to decimal conversion.